# How to have 100% opacity even when control is disabled in wpf C#

Tags: wpf

I have a textbox in my wpf, when I disable it the opacity decrease. This happens to tell the user that the textbox is not enable. Is there any way to disable a control and keep the look as the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `Template` property to your own custom `ControlTemplate`:

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="False" Margin="10">
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <!--<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                        </Trigger>-->
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `IsHitTestVisible="False"` instead of `IsEnabled="False"`