# WPF, Telerik: Change control style when disabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, raddropdownbutton

I have a trouble with Telerik control.

```
<Style x:Key="RadDropDownButtonStyle" TargetType="telerik:RadDropDownButton">
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="telerik:RadDropDownButton">
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="Red" />...
```

So, this handles Disabled property. Text changes its color, but it is not contrast, something like watermark.

How can I disable this? And make disabled control more contrast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Text changes its color, but it is not contrast, something like watermark.

For future references, this is caused by the `Opacity` property. When the opacity is lower than 1 it becomes lighter.

The problem you are describing is something very familiar. And I'm afraid there isn't any great way to get rid of this, so much so that the best advise that I can give you is to not even bother. If anything, it will just make using the themes and styles a real pain.

However there is an easy way to get your desired behaviour by replacing the `IsEnabled="False"` property with `IsHitTestVisible="False"` and `Focusable="False"` 

These will make it impossible to click or focus the control by keyboard navigation, basically making it disabled. Now you can add some more style properties to make it look the way you believe a disabled control should look like. By for example setting the wanted *Foreground* and *Background* or you could even use an *Opacity* closer to 1 (ex: 0.9) which will make it less dark than the original but still dark enough to read properly.

I hope this helps you with your current problem, just leave a comment if you want me to clarify further.

---

**EDIT 1:** Apperently can overwrite the opacity change by using your own `DataTemplate` for the control. [How to have 100% opacity even when control is disabled in wpf C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925946/how-to-have-100-opacity-even-when-control-is-disabled-in-wpf-c-sharp)

---

**EDIT 2:** I'll give you an example of how to use the other properties correctly.

This is how you would define a disabled button normally, and doing so will make the text lighter and less readable.

```
<!-- Simple disabled button -->
<telerik:RadButton Content="Test Button 1" IsEnabled="False" />

<!-- Button with binding on IsEnabled -->
<telerik:RadButton Content="Test Button 2" IsEnabled="{Binding MyBinding}" />
```

Now I'll show you how you can mimic these results by using the properties `IsHitTestVisible` and `Focusable`.

```
<!-- Simple disabled button -->
<telerik:RadButton Content="Test Button 1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False" />

<!-- Button with binding on IsEnabled -->
<telerik:RadButton Content="Test Button 2" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding MyBinding}" Focusable="{Binding MyBinding}" />
```

In the above examples, the buttons will look as if they are still enabled. However you won't be able to focus or click them. Of course we do want to see some difference to be able to tell that they can't be used.

```
<!-- Styled disabled button -->
<telerik:RadButton Content="Test Button 1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False" >
    <telerik:RadButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:RadButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsHitTestVisible}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadButton.Style>
</telerik:RadButton>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Changing Opacity property's value didnt help.
Have you got any variants?

Comment: That is not what I said. When the control get's disabled the `Opacity` changes automatically. It's pretty much impossible to stop it from happening. Have you tried using `IsHitTestVisible` and `Focusable`?

Comment: what I've tried:
`
<Trigger Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.95"/>
                        </Trigger>
<Trigger Property="Focusable" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.95"/>
                        </Trigger>
`

Comment: I see what you've edited. But I dont understand how to use it with telerik controls

Comment: To use what I posted in my first edit, you'll have to write your own custom template like in that example. For telerik specifically you can look at the documentation of implicit styles. But I've added a code example to show what I meant with those 2 properties, I hope this helps you further.